Issue in bitbucket pull request, extra curly brace added
I have changed one JSP file and committed that file to separate bitbucket branches 'A' & 'B'. Then, I created 'C' branch on top of 'B' branch.
'C' branch file has the same changes as 'A' & 'B' branches because 'C' is rebased on 'B'.
I committed a few more files to 'A' branch and created a pull request to 'C' branch to merge 'A' branch changes. That Pull request is created without conflict.
There is an issue in 'C' branch JSP file where one extra curly brace } is added by the pull request to a conditional if statement in my file.
Can someone help me understand why the pull request added an additional curly brace?

Please add some code snippets or the git output to your issue.
